Is there a point to reviewing/accepting suggested edits of tags on a poorly rated duplicate?
In the suggested edits review queue, I just came across a question that was poorly written (unclear, no concrete examples, strictly speaking two problems in one question, a duplicate, and only 1 very broad tag) and therefore downvoted and closed as duplicate.
Nevertheless someone (not the author) made an suggested edit to that question by adding more specific (correct) tags.
Now I wonder - I know the reason for duplicates being kept is to "increase the hitbox", basically the web of duplicates create a funnel to guide lots of differently asked questions and search queries to the "single source of wisdom". Does this apply to the tags, too? Which part do tags play in the game of making duplicates discoverable? Is it favorable to have duplicates sorted into more categories? Is a poor question a valuable part of that funnel that's worth maintaining?

I feel there are too many questions here. For what is worth, those are mostly horrible tags to add anyway, so the whole thing is moot.

@yivi: If you need exactly one question: "What's the point of putting effort into prettifying poorly written questions once they are marked as duplicates?" I'm not sure whether prettifying edits (and reviewing those) are beneficial or just a waste of time.

I think it is a waste of time for somebody who does not have the edit privilege to go around only editing or changing tags -- irrespective of whether the question is highly voted up or down. It is far easier for those who have the edit privilege to do so and this should be left to them. I notice that there are many high rep users who retag questions quite quickly, so I certainly don't think this is a good task for me. Personally, if the only edit being suggested is changing the tags, then I think there would be a case to automatically stop that suggested edit from being accepted by the system.

@PeterJames You mean "retag only edits" should be a priviledge to high rep users? Understandable, but it raises the entry bar to participation and incentivizes gaming the system by adding one minor edits like also fixing 1 typo (when there is more to do than just that). Doesn't really solve the issue I would think.

@PeterJames There are many tag-only edits that can be valuable suggestions. Like removing completely wrong tags (consider [[tag:java]] on a [[tag:javascript]] question, for example). Or adding a very relevant tag (e.g., tagging the library used on a question with just a generic language tag), I don't think such edits should be blocked. As long as the rest of the post is still presentable. Changing the tag but leaving some completely malformed code, is not a good suggestion, for example.

@LWChris What VLAZ said. But note that 10k+ users can edit tags inline, which is much faster than going through the usual editor interface.

A very simple tag only edit is quite likely to be accepted quickly by a low rep user, so if somebody wants to game the system, it seems that they just have to make lots of simple tag only edits on those types of questions without any other edits.

@PeterJames Yes, I would say that very simple tag edits are indeed a waste of everybody's time and effort. E.g., adding the [[tag:arrays]] tag or something overly generic does not really improve a post much. Many posts deal with arrays but the tag is often superfluous. That is not like tagging the correct technology used. However, I don't think we should forbid all suggested tag-only edits just because some can be abused. By the same logic, we should just not have suggested edits because anybody can do a bad job of it. And they often do.

@VLAZ Maybe the solution would be to allow tag only suggested edits, but simply not award any reputation for it. After all, tag only edits do not seem to count towards a user's "posts edited" total.

@PeterJames possible. I'd not be against it. But also, I can't really be bothered to FR it. Whether SE are up for it is another matter, of course.

@VLAZ Yes, I think it is one of those things that would end up at the end of a backlog, but I will search MSE one day to see if it has already been suggested. It would not surprise me if it has already been requested.

Question is nuked now, can we nuke that tag editor too?

"103 edit suggestions approved" Looks at bunch of those approved edits, that are do nothing to improve the post head desk. it's not just the tag editor that's the problem, it's also the blind auto reviewers, @IanKemp . If those people reviewed properly, then the editor would already be edit banned.

I have no words for this suggestion... The user that approved the edit, as part of an approve and edit, removed the tag the user that suggested the edit added, meaning that the only thing that changed was removed in the approval edit. >_< Why was that not rejected?!

@PeterJames The best way to search Meta is to post and wait for people to point out the duplicate /s But honestly I think there's much more behind this topic of "tag only edits" than I initially thought, and people have strong opinions and good reasons to be unsatisfied with the status quo. I could cook up a FR for changes to the system, I think...

@ThomA Please do raise a flag for moderators to review that user's bad edit suggestions--they can warn the user and the reviewers, or suspend their review privileges.

@TylerH , I already have; that specific edit was the "straw that broke the camels back".

@ThomA Gotcha. Thank you :-)

This answer is probably a little "biased", however, things like tag only edits to low quality posts, especially when other issues with the posts aren't addressed, is one of the reasons I don't visit the Edit review queue anymore.
Honestly, I don't see why these edits should be approved. If the post is a duplicate, and low-quality, it's very likely the post is not going to survive; it'll be deleted by the Roomba at some point in the (near) future. As such, if the edit were approved, the user who suggested the edit is likely to lose the reputation anyway.
For such edits, I would likely reject them, as it's unlikely to improve/salvage the post. If the post has (many) formatting/spelling/grammar issues, I will reject it; suggested edits should address as many of the problems with the post as possible, and leaving the post in a bad state with a suggestion means:

The editor didn't put the effort in the fix the problem(s) with the post
Is blocking others from improving the post, as no one else can edit the post until the edit review is completed
Reviewers will likely need to spend more time fixing the post than the editor did.
It uses up already very limited space in the queue, stopping someone else from (hopefully) suggesting a good edit.

Most of the time, when I saw tag only suggested edits, it was rare that there weren't other problems in the post that needing addressing. If the post was salvagable in other ways, so not off-topic or so low-quality it couldn't be answered, I would normally reject and edit it myself; and add the tags myself if I felt it appropriate. This might seem controversial to some, but in my opinion someone getting reputation for not actually addressing the problems with the post promotes users to continue to do that; they keep doing more (lazy) tag only edits and others start doing them too. If the post isn't salvagable, and the edit makes no attempt to fix other issues, then I would reject it and move on.

From my experience as well, if you continue to encounter such low quality edits from a single user, it's likely worth raising a custom flag on one of the posts that the user has made a suggested edit on, and explaining the problem you're seeing in detail. Moderators can then block the user from making further suggested edits (temporarily), and also reach out to the users that were approving the edits as well (and also review ban them if needed as well). If you're wondering what to write, a recent flag I raised had something similar to the following (anonymised) text:

I'm seeing a lot of bad tag only edits by the user <User Profile URL>. Here, for example, it's tag only but failed to address the formatting of the post. The same occured on <Post URL>. On another, <Post URL>, they removed code that had to be readded. Also feels like those that are approving aren't taking the time to actually properly review; the tag only edits are often irrelevant or not beneficial.


"No one else can edit the post until the edit review is completed" was news to me, which makes "The editor didn't put the effort in the fix the problem(s) with the post" a very relevant problem. Suddenly it feels like small incremental edits shouldn't be approved -> rewarded -> encouraged at all, only wholistic improvements or those that obviously attempted to catch everything and might just have missed something.

"only wholistic improvements or those that obviously attempted to catch everything and might just have missed something." This is very much my opinion for suggested edits. For unilateral edits, it's significantly less of an issue; tag only edits are much easier for high reputation users, and their edits don't need peer reviews nor block others from contributing.

@LWChris just for clarity, there are options to edit the post but you do have to deal with the suggested edit. Users with full edit privileges can use "Improve edit" which will accept it and the reviewer has to make a further edit. For cases where the suggested edit is good but maybe misses something small. For example, the suggested edit cleans up unneeded text, splits wall of text to paragraphs, formats the code. But misses, say, a couple of commas. The other option for a reviewer is "Reject and edit" which instead unilaterally rejects the edit and the reviewer has to edit themselves.

I'm already past that barrier, so I don't know the experience, but do new users know this? Are they told? Because my only other "community curated" experiences are Wikipedia and GitHub, and both systems welcome and encourage new users to submit small incremental edits, to lower the barrier of entrance and engagement. Wikipedia wouldn't reject a fixed deadlink just because there is 2 more of those. If I was new to this site and wasn't a perfectionist, with my other experiences, I could be the person to make small changes to posts with bigger problems.

The article on edits in the help centre does cover this, @LWChris : "Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged; try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe." (Emphasis [so]'s.)

@LWChris If you try to do a suggested edit a post, you get the following notification at the top of the screen: "We welcome edits that make the post easier to understand and more valuable for readers. Because community members review edits, please try to make the post substantially better than how you found it, for example, by fixing grammar or adding additional resources and hyperlinks." and some other advice on the side: https://i.sstatic.net/ykfjPNf0.png

@VLAZ Thank you for the screenshot. I feel that message could be clearer about that "significantly better" refers to "wholistic" rather than "substantial". Like "putting the code in a code block" makes it significantly better to read, but doesn't help if the rest of the question is still one long paragraph with bad grammar and punctuation.

I'd say that "significantly better" is unambiguous enough to, for example, mean "don't just edit th tags while leaving basically formatting issue in place", @LWChris . Unformatted code is trivial to fix; the "hard" work is fixing (sometimes very) poor spelling/grammar.

@LWChris I'm with you - I think more guidance is needed. I was just pointing out what is there already. There is more information in the help centre and on Meta. However, it isn't immediately available or well-advertised. There should be more just-in-time guidance and more links to resources at the very least.

It's unfortunate, but understandable, that you choose to avoid the edit review queue. The other problem with that queue is that so many edit reviewers simply approve almost every edit no matter how trivial or poor. There is an entire class of users (usernames end in "xWF", no idea what that means) who do nothing on the site except edits to add mostly irrelevant tags, and the majority of their edits are approved by reviewers.

I agree it's unfortunate, @PresidentJamesK.Polk . I know I'm not the one who has migrated away from the queue(s) as well, for similar reasons, which only compounds the problem of a lack of reviewers who value curation. I do, at least, peer review edits that I meet during my "natural" usage of the site, but that's obviously fee and far between sometimes.

"If the post is a duplicate, and low-quality, it's very likely the post is not going to survive" but it still will be used for suggested tags, which is something we want to avoid, specially if it's poor.

"If the post is a duplicate, and low-quality, it's very likely the post is not going to survive; it'll be deleted by the Roomba at some point in the (near) future. " Duplicates are never auto-deleted if they got a FGITW answer.

Don't get me started on the problem of FGITW answers, @KarlKnechtel ... Though, iirc, if it doesn't get upvoted/accepted, the question can still be roomba'd.

@ThomA only true for non-dupe closures - for those if all answers are <= 0, then the post can roomba. A dupe that has any answer will not.

Blargh, that just makes me dislike FGITW answers even more; looks like the downvote button is going to get even more use from me then...

It's particularly troublesome behavior when someone without edit privileges starts to edit a post before it is closed, when it is blatantly obvious that the post should be closed and not polished. Aka lipstick on a pig, when the correct user moderator action is to flag for closing/close vote. Editing literally achieves nothing but creates 100% pointless busy-work reviews. Such reviews should be rejected.

Yes, this MSE post is very relevant to that: Requesting a "Stop Polishing Turds" Edit Suggestion Reject Reason

Ah yes, yet another post with a Shog9 answer that basically says "nah it's cool bro". And now, here we sit.

I'm not sure he really says "It's cool", @IanKemp . They more sit on the side of that a "good defence" against the problem is getting the questions deleted as then the reputation is lost. Perhaps, if there is't one, there needs to be a [[meta-tag:feature-request]] for things like duplicates to be deleted, even if they get a FGITW answers with a score <=0.

@LWChris - a pending suggested edit blocks other suggested edits, but a high-rep user can make an edit themselves, automatically approving (or rejecting, their choice) the pending suggested edit.  The buttons that come up are "improve edit", "reject and edit", etc.  But if you just click "approve" and then later see something to edit, you're locked out until the review completes, which is really dumb.  Similar problem to when you vote to close with a reason other than duplicate, then you can't dup-hammer. (Oh, VLAZ already mentioned "improve edit".)

I fix tags on bad questions; but I'm not polluting the edit queue with them.

No.
Such edits serve only to obtain rep for the people making them. They are not only unhelpful, but actively harmful because they pollute the edit review queue with junk.
Will this ever be fixed? Almost certainly not. So just avoid the edit review queue.

Well, no. We need the edit review queue, as a teaching tool at the very least. And if people who care don't use the queue, that only leaves the robo-reviewers, which makes the problem worse.

It's not a useful teaching tool if it teaches the wrong thing i.e. that robo-reviewing is rewarded.

A teaching tool for editors, not reviewers. The suggested edit queue is supposed to be how we onboard new editors. That model stops working if all the good reviewers avoid the queue and only the robo-reviewers engage with it.

@Anerdw But that has already happened.

Okay, but that's not a reason to make it worse. Engaging with the Suggest edits queue is the only way we currently have to dynamically teach people how to make good edits. If you don't want to deal with that, fine - it's your time, and you get to choose how to use it. But don't holistically dismiss the system or tell everyone to avoid the queue. That just exacerbates the problem.

@Anerdw given the company's almost lack of any changes to address paint point in the queues, maybe we are teaching the company the wrong lesson. In fact, almost a year ago they made it essentially impossible for me to review suggested edits. Given the lack of urgency, at this point, it very much seems that it's what the company doesn't really want me to engage with the suggested edits review queue. I don't see why they'd want you or anybody else to do so, either. Seems very one-sided.
